# Google Compute Engine : Export and Import Compute-Engine(VM) info

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a copy of a VM(Compute Engine) from one project to another project, by taking a image of the boot disk and create a new instance using the image.
I want to export and import the VM's other info as well, like Tags, machine-type, zone, scope etc.

I am using gcloud console scripts to take images & creating VMs etc, since I have to migrate/copy many VMs at a time.

Please suggest a way to import/export Tags, machine-type, zone, scope etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Gather the [data](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource) via [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/) or [`gcloud compute`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/) command before you tear down the old instances
2. Provide that information [via API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setTags)  or [`gcloud compute` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) at creation-time or [configure](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setMetadata) the instances subsequent to creation
3. Enjoy your clones

The gathering and templating of this information in the language of API requests or shell commands is an exercise in parsing and templating with a pretty simple logic.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, but I want to use gcloud shell, API wont work through gcloud, sice that require authentication and so need to ssh into that VM.  gcloud compute instances describe <instance> command gives all the information in a "yaml" format, that makes parsing difficult

Comment: If you're set on shell methods rather than API, which is usually a more structured format such as JSON or XML, you can use shell-like methods to solve the problem. Use `cut`, `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, etc. in various combinations to parse shell output. That or dive into the SDK and log the retrieved API response in a structured format. Submit it to [the PIT](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) as a feature / patch request, and a command line option could be spawned.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy attributes of your VM you can use the 'Clone' button from your Developer Console->Compute Engine->VM Instance->INSTANCE-NAME page.

If you prefer API or command line, on the clone page at the bottom you can find the REST or command line equivalent.

Comment: The OP wants to create the new VM in a different project. How would that work with the "Clone" feature?

Comment: He can use REST or command line equivalent to copy the attributes of his current running VM and use the same when creating the new VM in an other project.